# $L^1$ convergence of $p$-bounded functions is $p-bounded$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset L^1$ be such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$.
And suppose that $\forall n \, \, \Vert f_n \Vert_p \le 1$ (with the usual $L^p$-norm) for some $p>1$.

Prove that $\Vert f \Vert_p \le 1$.

The hint given by the exercise is about using Fatou's Lemma, but I can't see useful ways to apply it.
This is my attempt:
$$
\int \underline{\lim} \vert f_n \vert^p \le \underline{\lim} \int \vert f_n \vert^p 
= \underline{\lim} \Vert f_n \Vert^p\le 1
$$
But I'm stuck here and cannot reconduct to $f$ (I cannot deduce any pointwise convergence).

Comment: Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed linear space and $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ w.r.t. $||\cdot||$, then $$||x_n||\to ||x||.$$

Comment: @Sumanta But he have different norms here. We know that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$, not in $L^p$.

Comment: Another thing that you can use $f_n\xrightarrow{\text{measure}}f$, so we have subsequence $f_{n_k}\xrightarrow{\text{a.e.}}f$.

Comment: $$
\int|f|^p=\int \underline{\lim} \vert f_{n_k} \vert^p \le \underline{\lim} \int \vert f_{n_k} \vert^p 
= \underline{\lim} \Vert f_{n_k} \Vert^p\le 1
$$

Comment: See here $L^1$ convergence implies convergence in measure. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281421/convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-in-measure

Comment: And measure convergence implies a convergence of a subsequence almost everywhere https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006091/convergence-in-measure-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere-of-a-subsequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\|f_n-f\|_1 \to 0$ implies there is  a subsequnce $f_{n_k}$ converging a.e. to $f$. So $\int |f|^{p} \leq \lim \inf \int |f_{n_k}|^{p} \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ then $f_n \to f$ in measure. Then use this [Exercise on convergence in measure (Folland, Real Analysis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76478/exercise-on-convergence-in-measure-folland-real-analysis)